# Linux server equivalent of Cisco Discovery Protocol (CDP)?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ethernet, cdp

I am wondering if there are any Linux tools out there which might aid in identification of hosts directly connected to each other (much like Cisco Discovery Protocol on switches)?

I have found http://sourceforge.net/projects/lcdpd/ which searching. But it appears to be a dead project and the patch is only for older kernels.

I am just trying to alleviate the tedious task of ethernet interface to ARP MAC address to hostname lookup. A bonus would be something that also announced its own neighbors so you could have a 2 hop view of the rest of network.

Comment: What's the use case here?

Comment: To help remotely identify port to port mapping of Linux machines connected to each other without a switch.

Comment: So you have a bunch of servers connected directly? Sound very painful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for [LLDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol)?

Agent software is [out there](http://www.open-lldp.org/open-lldp/man-pages/lldpad) for Linux, and many network devices support it.

Comment: Yep, this looks like what I was after. Actually, the Intel LLDP agent doesn't provide much information at all. With some more searching about LLDP I discovered https://github.com/vincentbernat/lldpd which does a simple output of the LLDP neighbors, their interface, MAC, hostname, IP address, and more. This becomes very helpful information when there are no switches to provide a MAC table.

Comment: The LLDP information also led me to http://www.netdisco.org/ which appears to be exactly what I was looking for.